# Non-empty value of Textbox.text being read as empty. Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, build, textbox

I'm trying to build a vb .net application in which I've several textboxes in my main form and they are filled with numerical values during design time.
The below image shows a snippet of my form:

[image]

But when I build the app, the filled numerical values are being read as empty strings ("").
Here's the exact error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

Here's a snippet of the autos window:
[image]

Notice in the Autos window the value of the text property of `TextBoxWireDiameter` is "". But I've added value to the text property in design time. The same error occurs for other textboxes I've filled as well. Any Idea why this is happening?

Here's my code:  (All subs contain the exact same code)

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub TextBoxWireLength_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxWireLength.TextChanged
    Dim WireArea As Double = Math.PI * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) / 4
    Dim WireMass As Double = 8400 * WireArea * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)
    TextBoxWireResistance.Text = ((TextBoxWireResistivity.Text * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)) / WireArea)
    TextBoxWireCurrent.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text / TextBoxWireResistance.Text
    TextBoxWirePower.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text * TextBoxWireCurrent.Text
    TextBoxWireHeat.Text = TextBoxWirePower.Text * TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.Text * 60
    TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text = TextBoxWireHeat.Text / (WireMass * 450)
    TextBoxWireTemperature.Text = TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text + 22
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxWireDiameter_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxWireDiameter.TextChanged
    Dim WireArea As Double = Math.PI * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) / 4
    Dim WireMass As Double = 8400 * WireArea * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)
    TextBoxWireResistance.Text = ((TextBoxWireResistivity.Text * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)) / WireArea)
    TextBoxWireCurrent.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text / TextBoxWireResistance.Text
    TextBoxWirePower.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text * TextBoxWireCurrent.Text
    TextBoxWireHeat.Text = TextBoxWirePower.Text * TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.Text * 60
    TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text = TextBoxWireHeat.Text / (WireMass * 450)
    TextBoxWireTemperature.Text = TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text + 22
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxWireResistivity_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxWireResistivity.TextChanged
    Dim WireArea As Double = Math.PI * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) / 4
    Dim WireMass As Double = 8400 * WireArea * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)
    TextBoxWireResistance.Text = ((TextBoxWireResistivity.Text * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)) / WireArea)
    TextBoxWireCurrent.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text / TextBoxWireResistance.Text
    TextBoxWirePower.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text * TextBoxWireCurrent.Text
    TextBoxWireHeat.Text = TextBoxWirePower.Text * TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.Text * 60
    TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text = TextBoxWireHeat.Text / (WireMass * 450)
    TextBoxWireTemperature.Text = TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text + 22
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxWireVoltage_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxWireVoltage.TextChanged
    Dim WireArea As Double = Math.PI * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) / 4
    Dim WireMass As Double = 8400 * WireArea * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)
    TextBoxWireResistance.Text = ((TextBoxWireResistivity.Text * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)) / WireArea)
    TextBoxWireCurrent.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text / TextBoxWireResistance.Text
    TextBoxWirePower.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text * TextBoxWireCurrent.Text
    TextBoxWireHeat.Text = TextBoxWirePower.Text * TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.Text * 60
    TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text = TextBoxWireHeat.Text / (WireMass * 450)
    TextBoxWireTemperature.Text = TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text + 22
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxWireCurrentDuration_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.TextChanged
    Dim WireArea As Double = Math.PI * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) * (TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000) / 4
    Dim WireMass As Double = 8400 * WireArea * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)
    TextBoxWireResistance.Text = ((TextBoxWireResistivity.Text * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)) / WireArea)
    TextBoxWireCurrent.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text / TextBoxWireResistance.Text
    TextBoxWirePower.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text * TextBoxWireCurrent.Text
    TextBoxWireHeat.Text = TextBoxWirePower.Text * TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.Text * 60
    TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text = TextBoxWireHeat.Text / (WireMass * 450)
    TextBoxWireTemperature.Text = TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text + 22
End Sub
End Class
```

Here's what I've tried to resolve the issue:

1. Rebuilding several time. --> No use.
2. Surrounded the textbox.text codes with val(), Cbdl() and TryParse(). --> Nothing worked.
3. Assigning values to the textboxes in the Form1.load event. --> No use.

Comment: I've temporarily deleted my answer, let me get some clarification. I guess when you put some value in `TextBoxWireLength`, its `TextChanged` events wants to get a value from `TextBoxWireLength` which is currently an empty string, and when that's unable to find it, the error's happening when filling up the first `TextBox`, isn't it?

Comment: @LinuXMan why is the textbox.text currently an empty string when I've assigned it a value at design time?

Comment: Is that problem happening when you put something on the first TextBox or for all?

Comment: @LinuXMan its happening for all textboxes from which the values are being read during the textchanged events.

Comment: The problem seems a bit complicated. Please forward me your project via GitHub or Drive on my Gmail. I'll notify you as soon as I fix it.

Comment: @LinuXMan sure I will.

Comment: The form has not completed loading/initializing when the text changed event fires. You can verify this by putting breakpoints in the text changed event and the end of the form load event.  Also, textchanged is going to fire with every key stroke.

Comment: @JimHewitt ok. So what am I supposed to do so that form loads completely before the textchanged events are fired? Or is there any other workaround for this issue?

Comment: Well, one way is to declare a Boolean at the form level, say `formLoaded` and initialize it to `false`.  Then in the form load event set it to true.  Then wrap all your textchanged events with a `If formLoaded  Then`.  Not sure if that is the best way to fix this.

Comment: @JimHewitt ok I'll give it a try n see if it works.

Comment: @LinuXMan Here's the linknto my project: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=16V0_dS9AJyT3h1hmrL94Ove7iq4AJZzm

Comment: @JimHewitt your suggestion works fine too. Thanks.

Comment: Not a good idea to just swallow exceptions, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, gotcha! I fixed your problem so much easily. Just use `Try Catch` in all `TextChange` events. For example:

```
Private Sub TextBoxWireCurrentDuration_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.TextChanged
    Try
        Dim WireArea As Double = Math.PI * Val((TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000)) * Val((TextBoxWireDiameter.Text / 1000)) / 4
        Dim WireMass As Double = 8400 * WireArea * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)
        TextBoxWireResistance.Text = ((TextBoxWireResistivity.Text * (TextBoxWireLength.Text / 1000)) / WireArea)
        TextBoxWireCurrent.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text / TextBoxWireResistance.Text
        TextBoxWirePower.Text = TextBoxWireVoltage.Text * TextBoxWireCurrent.Text
        TextBoxWireHeat.Text = TextBoxWirePower.Text * TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.Text * 60
        TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text = TextBoxWireHeat.Text / (WireMass * 450)
        TextBoxWireTemperature.Text = TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text + 22
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Chill man. It's working perfectly now.

[image: Easy Solution]

Comment: If I'm not wrong CInt returns an integer. But I want textbox.text to return a decimal number because sometimes the wire has a diameter of 0.5 or 1.46 etc.

Comment: Please don't write an empty Catch. It will swallow errors in your code and give unexpected results.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: This just horrifies me. You are doing all this arithmetic with strings!

Comment: @Mary strings get automatically converted to whatever datatype matches the text.

Comment: @Somanna TURN ON OPTION STRICT NOW! You cannot depend on things being converted as you expect. Also fix the redundant code and get it out of the .TextChanged event

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

I would not run this code every time the user enters a digit. Ideally I would add a calculate button so the user can complete their entries. At least change it to the `.Leave` event.

Do not repeat the code 5 times. This makes it very hard to maintain if you have to make a change in 5 different places. Make a separate `Sub` and call it from the events.

The validation code could be in an `If` statement so you don't end up with a bunch of zeros.

```
    If Not Double.TryParse(TextBoxWireDiameter.Text, WireDiameter) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

The calculations can be combined with the display code. I kept it separate for clarity.

```
Private Sub TextBoxWireCurrentDuration_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.Leave
    Calculate()
End Sub

Private Sub Calculate()
    'Declare numeric variables
    Dim WireDiameter As Double
    Dim WireLength As Double
    Dim WireResistivity As Double
    Dim WireResistance As Double
    Dim WireVoltage As Double
    Dim WireCurrent As Double
    Dim WirePower As Double
    Dim WireCurrentDuration As Double
    Dim WireHeat As Double
    Dim WireTemperatureRise As Double
    Dim WireTemperature As Double
    'Parse user input
    Double.TryParse(TextBoxWireDiameter.Text, WireDiameter)
    Double.TryParse(TextWireLength.Text, WireLength)
    Double.TryParse(TextBoxWireResistivity.Text, WireResistivity)
    Double.TryParse(TextBoxWireVoltage.Text, WireVoltage)
    Double.TryParse(TextBoxWireCurrentDuration.Text, WireCurrentDuration)
    'Calculations
    Dim WireArea = Math.PI * ((WireDiameter / 1000) ^ 2)
    Dim WireMass = 8400 * WireArea * WireLength
    WireResistance = WireResistivity * (WireLength / 1000) / WireArea
    WireCurrent = WireVoltage / WireResistance
    WirePower = WireVoltage * WireCurrent
    WireHeat = WirePower * WireCurrentDuration * 60
    WireTemperatureRise = WireHeat / (WireMass * 450)
    WireTemperature = WireTemperatureRise + 22
    'Display results
    TextBoxWireResistance.Text = WireResistance.ToString("N4")
    TextBoxWireCurrent.Text = WireCurrent.ToString("N2")
    TextBoxWirePower.Text = WirePower.ToString("N3")
    TextBoxWireHeat.Text = WireHeat.ToString("N0")
    TextBoxWireTemperatureRise.Text = WireTemperatureRise.ToString("N4")
    TextBoxWireTemperature.Text = WireTemperature.ToString("N4")
End Sub
```